# Wordpress API doesn't return any post

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I need to fetch all the posts from my WordPress website (they are in the **job_listing category**). I tried using the API with this route wp-

> json/wp/v2/posts?id=
>
> json/wp/v2/posts?categories

The two URL returns me an empty array. The `/post` URL without parameters also returns me an empty array.

How can I handle it?

Thanks

Comment: to get the categories `/wp-json/wp/v2/categories` -  to get the posts `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

Comment: to get the posts of a category `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=1` where 1 is the category ID